# Revert shell without using explorer

Tags: windows, shell, windows-7, registry

I've been playing around with a Windows 7 virtual machine and found that by changing the shell registry value in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell I can use an arbitrary program (for example, paint) as the shell instead of explorer.

Now, given that I have no access to the tools afforded by explorer, how would I go about reverting this? This seems like a rather useful trick for demo machines and such, so I would hope that there's a way to revert them when done.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that keyboard commands (C-S-ESC, C-M-DEL) still work. Surprisingly, windows-r doesn't work. To revert it, open the task manager using C-S-ESC, then click new task, then you can either run explorer to start the gui shell, or regedit to change the default shell.